# Getting a single resource from a JNLP file

Tags: java, url, java-web-start, jnlp

If I open a `.jnlp` file I see that it's just an xml with elements such as `.jar` files and other resources like images. I can currently get the `jnlp` file by writing:

```
final URL jnlp = new URL("http://<host>:<port>/<file>.jnlp");
final ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(jnlp.openStream());
final FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("<file>.jnlp");
stream.getChannel().transferFrom(channel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

I want to parse the `.jnlp` *(using a standard xml parser)* and grab particular files from the server without using the `javaws` command. I imagine the URL is some concatenation of the `codebase` attribute and `href` values for the `jar` or `icon` elements..

Anyone know if this possible// what my next steps should be?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself-- It is just concatenating the URL for the `codebase` with the `href`!

(*I input the wrong string while I was testing. /rant*)

For example:

to get `test.jar` from the bellow `.jnlp` you use the URL `http://<host>:<port>/dir/test.jar`

```
<jnlp spec="1.5+"
  version="8.0"
  codebase="http://<host>:<port>/dir" ... >
    ...
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="256m"/>
        <jar href="test.jar" download="eager"/>
    ...
```